# how to prevent upload Pornographic pictures to stackoverflow user profile

Tags: discussion, profile-page, images

Recently I have noticed this phenomenon , that user upload pornographic pictures to there profile on the stackoverflow site,

who to prevent this ?

like :

https://stackoverflow.com/users/427598/damluar

https://stackoverflow.com/users/523725/lobo
...

Comment: they didn't upload pictures to stackoverflow, but to gravatar.com, but those pics looks ok for me, :D, you can flag one of their post, and inform moderator about that, btw.

Comment: That is not pornography.

Comment: so what is pornography ?

Comment: @haim good question. There is a [definition from a justice of the U.S. supreme court](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_know_it_when_I_see_it) that I like very much (paraphrasing): "It's impossible to define, but I know it when I see it"

Comment: How do we get them to do it *more*?  ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess you would have to report offending Gravatars to [Gravatar](http://www.gravatar.com) directly. I expect they do some form of basic content filtering anyway .

If you ask me, though, none of these images can be classified as even remotely pornographic by most today's standards. Advertising on any western TV station or magazine will show more arousing imagery.